# Methodology for estimating costs of a master’s program before seeking official approval for the program

Tags: masters, funding, fees, administration

Do you happen to know any methodology for estimating the cost of a master’s program at university level before proposing and asking for approval of that program and cost by the state or the university authorities?

Comment: Do you mean the cost for a student taking the program, the cost for the university to run the program, or something else?